# Change HTML as an input field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a registration form that asks for a few basic details. I would like to be able to add the person's first name to a question that's on the same page, without submitting the form to do it.

i.e. As the page loads, the question will be, "Is Attendee 1 a delegate?", but when they type in their name, it will change to "Is Matthew a delegate?"

The questions are on the same page, so I know this has to be done with jQuery somehow...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is no need for database query, then `$('#element').blur(function(){/*do your thing here*/})`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML looked something like this

```
<div>Is <strong id='name'>Attendee 1</strong> a delegate?</div>
<input type='text' id='name-input'></input>
```

Then you could achieve this without jQuery like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init() {
  var input, name;
  input = document.getElementById('name-input');
  name = document.getElementById('name');

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var value = input.value;
    if(value.length === 0) {
      value = 'Attendee 1';
    }
    name.innerHTML = value;
  });

}
```

Of course, you could do the same thing with jQuery, but this is exactly the kind of thing that the two-way binding libraries and Frameworks lend themselves to. This is how I would go about doing it in AngularJS.

```
<div ng-controller='MyFormController'>
  <div>Is <strong ng-bind='name'></strong> a delegate?</div>
  <input type='text' ng-model='name'></input>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
function MyFormController($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'Attendee 1';
}
```

Angular, Ember, Backbone and Knockout are all good things to look into!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the OnBlur attribute on your .  Call a function within OnBlur that extracts the data from the input and puts it into the label.

In the HTML use tags to surround the data that you want to dynamically replace.  Locate those tags with the JavaScript or JQuery and replace the data inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange="document.getElementById('name_new').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value"/>
        <div> Is <strong id='name_new'>Attendee 1</strong> a delegate?</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Writing your JS inside your HTML is probably a bad idea. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Comment: You are right but he can take the onChange listener to another js file, thanks for your comment.